# Modify Search Record in PeopleSoft

Tags: date, search, peoplesoft

First of all, i would like to find an existing value in my SQL View table,

see this input:
https://flic.kr/p/xwhRdx

When i input Begin Date and end Date , i want those input to search another field in my SQL view table, that is Form Receive Date.
Example: i have 2 rows with Form Receive Date 17-Sep-2015 and 20-Sep-2015.
 When i input Begin Date: 18-Sep-2015 and End Date: 25 Sep-2015, it will search Form Receive date between 18-Sep-2015 and 25-Sep-2015 and will find a row with 20-Sep-2015 as it Form Receive Date.

Is it possible to modify that search function ? Because when i modify the query view and add where FormReceiveDate between BeginDate and EndDate, it search in my SQL table record and it will find nothing because my BeginDate and EndDate is null.

thx before :D

Answer (score 0):

If the column you want to search on is in the same search record, then just designate the Form Receive Date column as a Search Key in the search record field properties. This will add another search field called Form Receive Date to the search page, but will still keep the start date and end date fields, if you want to get rid of those then uncheck those fields as Search Keys in the field properties.